# jQuery UI tabs keeping date filter same across tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I have multiple 5 tabs, and each tab has a date filter. What I would like to do is that if I change date in one tab, it should show same date in date filter across all tabs. Currently, if first tab is 5/18, all other tabs show current date or date set within that tab. I want if one tab selects 5/18, it should automatically change that date for all tabs. Also tabs is being called on one page and Date is on ajax page.

Tabs Page:  HTML

```
      <div id="tabScheduleEvents">
            <ul>
                <cfloop query="qAllScheduleEvents">
                    
                    <li><a href="##tab-#qAllScheduleEvents.ScheduleEventID#">#qAllScheduleEvents.Name#</a></li>
                </cfloop>
            </ul>

            <cfloop query="qAllScheduleEvents">
            
                <cfset Request.Attributes.Shop_LocationID = Variables.LocationID>
                <cfset Request.Attributes.ScheduleEventID = qAllScheduleEvents.ScheduleEventID>

                <div id="tab-#qAllScheduleEvents.ScheduleEventID#>
                    <cfinclude template="/scheduler/_ajax/Timeline.cfm">
                </div>
            </cfloop>
        
        </div>
```

JQuery:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#tabScheduleEvents").tabs();
    });
  </script>
```

Timeline page:

HTML page:

```
   <div>
    <label><strong>Date:</strong></label>
    <input type="text" id="EventDate#Request.Attributes.ScheduleEventID#" name="EventDate" value="#DateFormat(Now(), 'm/d/yyyy')#">
    
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#EventDate<cfoutput>#Request.Attributes.ScheduleEventID#</cfoutput>').change(function()
{
    var EventDate = $(this).val();

    objCal.setOptions(
    {
        'selectedDate': EventDate
    });

    $.getJSON('/scheduler/_ajax/ListScheduleEventJobs.cfm?&StartDate=' + $('#EventDate<cfoutput>#Request.Attributes.ScheduleEventID#</cfoutput>').val(), function (events) {
        objCal.setEvents(events);

        
});
```

Comment: As a reminder, we need an example from the rendered HTML not the original ColdFusion. JS/jQuery is a Client-side scripting language and will only be interacting with the DOM in the browser. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I also see that you are missing `"` in your DIV ID.